# ¿Comó insertar en un campo foraneo de tabla, el valor de campo clave PK de tabla relacionada , con un select dinamico?

Tags: php, mysql

```html
//archivo recibe el formmulario
$conexion = conectar();

  $grupo      =  $_POST['numgpo'];
  $capacidad  =  $_POST['capacidad'];
  $aula       =  $_POST['aula'];
  $turno      =  $_POST['turno'];
  $periodo    =  $_POST['periodo'];
  $materia    =  $_POST['materia'];
  $profesor   =  $_POST['profesor'];
  $lunes      =  $_POST['lunes'];
  $martes     =  $_POST['martes'];
  $miercoles  =  $_POST['miercoles'];
  $jueves     =  $_POST['jueves'];
  $viernes    =  $_POST['viernes'];

  $a = "INSERT INTO grupos(NumGpo, capacidad, aula, turno, periodo, materia, profesor, 
                           lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes) 
                           VALUES ('$grupo', '$capacidad', '$aula', '$turno', '$periodo', '$materia', '$profesor', 
                                   '$lunes', '$martes', '$miercoles', '$jueves', '$viernes')";

  $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $a)or die (mysqli_error($conexion));

  echo $consulta;
```

```js
$conexion = conectar(); //archivo externo

$periodos = "SELECT * FROM periodos";
$resultPeriodos = mysqli_query($conexion, $periodos);

$materias = "SELECT * FROM materias";
$resultMaterias = mysqli_query($conexion, $materias);

$profesores = "SELECT *  FROM profesores";
$resultProfesores = mysqli_query($conexion, $profesores);

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="periodo">Periodo:</label>
    <select name="periodo" id="periodo" class="form-control">
  <?php while ($peri = mysqli_fetch_array($resultPeriodos, MYSQLI_NUM)) { ?>
      <option value="<?php $peri[0] ?>"><?php echo $peri[2]; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
<label for="materia">Materia:</label>
 <select name="materia" id="materia" class="form-control">
  <?php while ($mate = mysqli_fetch_array($resultMaterias, MYSQLI_NUM)) { ?>          <option value="<?php $mate[0] ?>"><?php echo $mate[2]; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
   </select>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div>
   <label for="profesor">Nombre Profesor:</label>
<select name="profesor" id="profesor" class="form-control">
   <?php while ($profe = mysqli_fetch_array($resultProfesores, MYSQLI_NUM)) { ?>
  <option value="<?php $profe[0] ?>"><?php echo $profe[2]; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Error**: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vasco`.`grupos`, CONSTRAINT `grupos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`materia`) REFERENCES `materias` (`idMateria`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

**El error dice**: el `idMateria` (seguramente en la variable `$materia`) no existe en la tabla `materias` y por esa razón no te dejara insertar el nuevo `grupo`.

Si te fijas detenidamente, te esta faltando `echo` en los `value` de los `option`, por ejemplo:

```
<option value="<?php $peri[0] ?>"><?php echo $peri[2]; ?></option>
```

Deberías cambiarlos a algo así:

```
<option value="<?php echo $peri[0] ?>"><?php echo $peri[2]; ?></option>
```

//

Considera realizar validar los datos antes de hacer un `insert/update`, por ejemplo:

1. Validar el tipo/formato de datos.
2. Validar existencia de `ids` de registros relacionados (eg: idMateria, idGrupo)

**NOTA**: Te recomiendo que leas este articulo sobre [SQL Injection](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: gracias, los id se supone los pone dentro del bucle, y existen porque la consulta a la que se le aplica el fetch_all() selecciona todos los registros, pero sigue marcando el mensaje, algo mas me esta fallando

Comment: de acuerdo, ya esta al final del archivo, una disculpa por el formato de los codigos

Comment: Imprime directo el error de:: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails, que puse arriba, por que no esta ni siquiera los valores de los <select> desde ahi esta mal. debe ser incorrecta la forma como los estoy poniendo

Comment: asi era como lo estaba intentando, pero no esta recibiendo los valores de selects

Comment: es cierto una parte era por eso, muchas gracias por todo saludos

Answer (score 0):

La función `mysqli_query` retorna un valor de tipo [Mysqli_Result](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php)

No es un objeto iterable "per se", luego no puedes usarlo directamente en una estructura `foreach`. En su lugar llama a uno de sus método fetch_x (array, assoc, num)

```
<?php while($mate = $materias->fetch_assoc()): ?>
   <option value="<?php $mate['idMateria'] ?>">
       <?php echo $mate['materia']; ?>
   </option>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, ya lo cambie pero e error sigue marcando. Los ids que intento insertar existen porque son todos los que selecciona la consulta de la tabla. Algo mas me falla.